# PHPMailer send address failed

Tags: php

I have this PHP code using the PHPMailer library

```
 $email = new PHPMailer();

$email->IsSMTP();
$email->SMTPAuth   = $Email_SMTPAuth;
$email->Host       = $Email_Host;
$email->Port       = $Email_Port;
$email->Username   = $Email_Username;
$email->Password   = $Email_Password;

$email->setFrom($result["emailfrom"], $result["fromname"]);

$email->Subject   = stripslashes($result["subject"]);
$email->Body      = stripslashes($result["message"]);

$email->AddAddress("email@domain.com");

if(!$email->Send()) {
    echo $email->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'sent';
}
```

When it fails to send, it show the error message:

```
The following From address failed: *EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE* : Called Mail() without being connected
```

Comment: You're not showing us the whole code.

Comment: @user3355243 check my update for the extra bit of code

Comment: google this https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=PHPMailer++Called+Mail%28%29+without+being+connected&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=pYfHVLHfO4GrU_vCgPAH and many answers will present themselves. You'll have to find which works for you because you've not shown your details here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it can be something to do with your host and port configuration, PHP Mailer might not be able to connect to your server with the settings you provided, thus giving you this error. Try checking again the configuration you set up, the host, port and username with your host and see if everything's all right.

[Here](https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/phpmailer-called-mail-without-being-connected) is something similar to the error you're getting. Hope it helps :)

Comment: i have tried using port 8025 and 2525 which the SMTP provider suggested but its not even hitting their servers

Comment: You might want to contact your SMTP Provider and, like @Spyryto said on his answer, "ask the provider to open the port to the host". Maybe they are there but they need to open it for your application, or there is some kind of misconfiguration by their side. 

Either way, the provider is the one to give you answers now, I guess. Let us know if you get the issue fixed :)

Answer (score 1):

It happens frequently to me... when I forget to ask the provider to open a port to the host.

I have several sites hosted by a provider, and a DEM application running on the server. Depending on the provider, the server can be secured so that you are not allowed to connect freely to any SMTP host/port, but you have to be enabled to.