# SMTP mail sending failed for webmail Address

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have SMTP mail sending function

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
            $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
            $mail->Port = 465;
            $mail->Username = "abc@gmail.com";
            $mail->Password = "*****";
            $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
            $mail->SetFrom("abc@mjsofttech.com", 'Admin');
            $mail->AddReplyTo("abc@mjsofttech.com", 'Admin');
            $mail->AddAddress($_POST['email']);
            $mail->Subject = $subject;
            $mail->WordWrap = 80;


  $mail->MsgHTML($msg);
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            if (!$mail->Send()) {
                $this->view->status = 'invalid';
            }
```

this code is working for Gmail address like xyz@gmail.com.and not working means I got message mail **send successfully** but lag to get the mail. it takes a long time for webmail address like xyz@company.com.but for Gmail address I will get immediately. Please help me. why does this happen? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer send address failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28170560/phpmailer-send-address-failed)

Comment: check the mail response in your logs

Comment: You must authenticate your email with your password before sending, so it won't get blocked in the server. if you use mail class like phpmailer to send mails, following example will help you.          

https://phpmailer.worxware.com/
               or                         
http://phpcode.mypapit.net/sending-mail-using-smtp-with-phpmailer/26/